# Behavior of Array#reject and Array#map iterater

Tags: ruby

I have a hash of dates:

```
values = {a: Time.now, b: Time.now - 3.days}
# => {:a=>2015-11-24 22:35:56 +0900, :b=>2015-11-21 22:35:56 +0900}
```

To select the values whose date is within one day from now, I wrote:

```
values.reject{|i, v| v < Time.now - 1.day}
# => {:a=>2015-11-24 22:35:56 +0900}
```

When I use `i[1]` instead of `v`, that doesn't work,

```
values.reject{|i| i[1] < Time.now - 1.day}
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass
```

while with `map`, it works.

```
values.map{|i| i[1]}
# => [2015-11-24 22:35:56 +0900, 2015-11-21 22:35:56 +0900]
```

Why does `Array#reject` behave differently?

Comment: There are no arrays in your code.

Comment: You use Hash.reject instead. I guess key and value are bind to different variables. Therefore the parameter destruction of arrays does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Hash.html#method-i-reject

`Hash#reject` yields the key and the value to the block. `i` is just the key. Your keys are symbols; presumably array accessor (`i[1]`) on symbols returns `nil`.

`Hash#map` isn't a thing, I guess. You're probably getting `Enumerable#map`. `Hash` is an `Enumerable`, so you can still call `map` on hashes.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map

`Enumerable#map` is yielding each key-value pair from the hash as a 2-element array:`[:a, 2015-11-24 22:35:56 +0900]`

BTW in many languages hashes are called associative arrays. Rubyists usually call them hashes.

Answer (score 1):

`reject` is a method on `Hash`, which takes a block with two block variables: the key and the value. If you pass it a block with only one variable like so:

```
some_hash.reject{|x| ...}
```

then `x` will be assigned the key, and its corresponding value is not accessible. Doing `x[1]` calls the symbol method `[]` on `x`, which gives `nil` because `:a` and `:b` are only one character long.

On the other hand, `Enumerable#map` implicitly casts the hash to an array, and takes a block with one block variable. If you actually pass it a block with one variable like so:

```
some_hash.map{|x| ...}
```

then `x` will be an array that has a key-value pair. Doing `x[1]` calls the array method `[]`, and returns the value of the hash.

If you instead pass a block with two variables like so:

```
some_hash.map{|x, y| ...}
```

then destruction will be implicitly applied to adjust the number of variables, i.e., the live about would be interpreted as:

```
some_hash.map{|(x, y)| ...}
```

and `x`, `y` would restrictively be the key and the value.

Probably you were confused because `Array#reject` takes a block with only one variable, and works differently with `Hash#reject`.